# DolphinDB error: SegmentedTable does not support direct access. Please use sql query to retrieve data

Tags: database, csv, export, dolphindb

```
dbDir = '/tests/dolphindb/valueDB'
devDir = '/tests/dolphindb/dev.csv'
db = database(dbDir)
dev = db.loadTable(`dev)
saveText(dev, devDir)
```

I want to export table "dev" as 'csv' file but I encountered this error message:

```
Execution was completed with exception
SegmentedTable does not support direct access. Please use sql query to retrieve data
```

I wonder if I have to load all data into memory to export it as 'csv' file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the input table for `saveText` must be a non-partitioned table.